# I need to get the key that has the value > 0

Tags: javascript

I need to get the key that has the value > 0 in this example would be 005340302403, how could I do that?

```
var json = {
    "productSkuInventoryStatus": {
        "005340304004": 0,
        "005340304003": 0,
        "005340304002": 0,
        "005340304001": 0,
        "005340302401": 0,
        "005340302402": 0,
        "005340301401": 0,
        "005340304005": 0,
        "005340301403": 0,
        "005340302405": 0,
        "005340301402": 0,
        "005340301405": 0,
        "005340302403": 1,
        "005340301404": 0,
        "005340302404": 0
    }
}

var array1 = Object.values(json.productSkuInventoryStatus);
const found = array1.find(element => element > 0); 
console.log(found)// get de value > 0
// how to get the key of this value greater than 0
```

Comment: use Object.entries you will get [key,value] pair. Now you can get both the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Object.keys` and `Array.find` to get the single key from the object.

```js
var json = {
    "productSkuInventoryStatus": {
        "005340304004": 0,
        "005340304003": 0,
        "005340304002": 0,
        "005340304001": 0,
        "005340302401": 0,
        "005340302402": 0,
        "005340301401": 0,
        "005340304005": 0,
        "005340301403": 0,
        "005340302405": 0,
        "005340301402": 0,
        "005340301405": 0,
        "005340302403": 1,
        "005340301404": 0,
        "005340302404": 0
    }
}

const result = Object.keys(json.productSkuInventoryStatus).find(key => json.productSkuInventoryStatus[key] > 0);
console.log(result)
```

To get all the keys from the object with `value > 0`, then `Array.filter` can be used. The resultant of this operation is an array.

```js
var json = {
  "productSkuInventoryStatus": {
    "005340304004": 0,
    "005340304003": 0,
    "005340304002": 0,
    "005340304001": 0,
    "005340302401": 0,
    "005340302402": 0,
    "005340301401": 0,
    "005340304005": 0,
    "005340301403": 0,
    "005340302405": 0,
    "005340301402": 0,
    "005340301405": 0,
    "005340302403": 1,
    "005340301404": 0,
    "005340302404": 0
  }
}

const result = Object.keys(json.productSkuInventoryStatus).filter(key => json.productSkuInventoryStatus[key] > 0);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` for this.

```
const result = Object.entries(json.productSkuInventoryStatus).filter(item => item[1] > 0).map(item => item[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through object keys like this, just another approach

```
let greater = "";
for(let prop in json.productSkuInventoryStatus){
  if(json.productSkuInventoryStatus[prop] > 0) greater = prop;
}
console.log(greater);
```